# Playing HD video on netbook

Tags: hdvideo, avchd

I have a HD video file with the following specs.

```
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames        : 5 frames
Muxing mode                      : Container profile=Unknown@4.1
Codec ID                         : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                         : 1h 46mn
Bit rate                         : 4 374 Kbps
Width                            : 1 280 pixels
Height                           : 688 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 1.860
Frame rate                       : 23.976 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.207
Stream size                      : 3.16 GiB (72%)
```

The video doesn't play well in my netbook [Acer AoA 150](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EYVBE0) . [Coreavc](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc) seems to say it can play even on netbooks but with Nvidia cards. How can I play it on my netbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hardware is way too slow for this video. The Atom N270 you have is about as slow as a Pentium III. The video is compressed, so the processor has to decompress it real time, and 1860x688 pixels are just too much for your processor, it cannot decompress 24 frames per second. The thing about netbooks with nvidia cards is that they have either CUDA (a technology which lets the processor to delegate computations to the GPU) or a dedicated hardware chip for decoding MPEG compressed videos, which cannot do anything else, but is especially efficient at MPEG. There is no way to add either to your netbook.

If you really insist to watch this video on your netbook, you'll have to reencode it in another scale, and preferably also in another (older, uglier, less computing-intensive) format like DivX. Your netbook has a 1024x600 screen, so recoding the video in 512x300 should still show up as a good quality. But reencoding is very slow. If you are doing it on the netbook, it will take 3-4 days. So if you have another, faster machine, where you can reencode, and a very strong reason to want to watch on the netbook, this could be a solution. But for most cases, it is just not worth the effort.

Comment: thanks for the good analysis..I'm curious to know the limitations of the Nvidia Ion based netbooks then...what resolution can they play well because HD can be many resolutions???

Comment: There is no way to answer this, because it depends on many more things than resolution. These fall into three categories: the options used for encoding (resolution, codec, bitrate, amount of b-frames i-frames and p-frames, block size, block shape, movement search algorithm type, etc.), video content (how many pixels change from one picture to the next), and options used for decoding (e.g. deinterlace algorithm choice). So the computing power needed for fluid playback is different for every single video file.